polynomial $F$ divides $G$ if and only if the same holds for their homgenisations?
Let $F, G$ be polynomials in $k[x_1, .., x_n]$. Let $\beta(F)$ denote the homogenisation of $F$,
$$
\beta(F) = x_0^{\deg F} F( x_1/x_{0}, ..., x_n/x_0 ). 
$$
Is it the case that $F|G$ if and only if $\beta(F) | \beta(G)$?
I can see that the latter implying the former is true, by setting $x_0 = 1$. But I wasn't sure about the other direction... Is the other direction true?
Any input appreciated. Thank you

Just use the definitions. If $G=FH$, take homogenization on both sides.

@Mark -- this, maybe with a one sentence explanation of why $\beta(FH) = \beta(F) \beta(H)$ to make a new student's life easier, should be an answer rather than a comment.
